# How do I resolve the issue of TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a reactjs app that should be returning data from a WepAPI. The dispatch I call on a function seems to be giving me this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

I have used other functions through dispatch and it worked fine but this one still sticks out.

The intended result is for the data to get back to the initial dispatch. At the moment the data comes through but is stuck when returning to the initial call.

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { jobActions } from '../../actions/job.actions';
import Popup from 'reactjs-popup'
import JwPagination from 'jw-react-pagination';


class LoadTable extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            data: [],
            pagination: [],
            Search: "Search",            
            sort: {
                column: null,
                direction: 'desc',
            },
        }
        this.clearSearch = this.clearSearch.bind(this);
        this.doSearch = this.doSearch.bind(this);
        this.doSort = this.doSort.bind(this);
        this.runLog = this.runLog.bind(this);
        this.openRunLog = this.openRunLog.bind(this);
        this.onChangePage = this.onChangePage.bind(this);
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getJobs() 
            .then((res) => {
                this.setState({
                    data: res.results.response || []
                })
            });

    }
    clearSearch() {
        this.props.getJobs()
            .then((res) => {
                this.setState({
                    data: res.results.response || [], Search: "Search",                    
                    sort: {
                        column: null,
                        direction: 'desc',
                    }
                })
            });
    }
    doSearch(e) {
        const { name, value } = e.target;        
        this.setState({ [name]: value });        

        this.props.doSearch(value)<----Initial Call
            .then((res) => {                
                this.setState({
                    data: res.results.response || [],
                    sort: {
                        column: null,
                        direction: 'desc',
                    }                    
                })
            });
    }
   render() {
         return  (
use data
)}
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({    
    getJobs: () => dispatch(jobActions.getJobs()),
    doSearch(value) {
        dispatch(jobActions.doSearch(value));<----dispatch
    },

});
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoadTable); 
==========================================
Action being called:
function doSearch(value) {     
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({ type: jobConstants.JOB_REQUEST });
        return jobService.doSearch(value)
            .then(
            results => {

                    dispatch({ type: jobConstants.JOB_SUCCESS, user });

                     //Ran console logs and seen the results here

                    return { results };
                },
                error => {
                    dispatch({ type: jobConstants.JOB_FAILURE, error });                    
                }
            );
    }
}
=========================
Services

function doSearch(SearchValue) {

    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        }),
        body: JSON.stringify({SearchValue})
    };

    const requestPath = 'http://localhost:53986/api/jobs/postsearch';    
    return fetch(requestPath, requestOptions)
        .then(handleResponseToJson)
        .then(response => {  
            if (response) {
                return { response };
            }           
        }).catch(function (error) {            
            return Promise.reject(error);
        });
}
```

Comment: hard to read with multiple functions called `doSearch` but the issue is the function doesn't have a return value specifically a `Promise`

Comment: In the actions?

Comment: i assume `jobService.doSearch(value)` but without the stack call logic, I can't be sure

Comment: oh jobService.doSearch(value) is another function that does the API call. I will update the post with that code.

Comment: In `mapDispatchToProps` you have to do `return dispatch(jobActions.doSearch(value));`

Comment: @DonovanM Do I wrap the return around all my dispatch?

Comment: You just have to put `return` in the beginning of that line from what I can tell. Right now `doSearch` in `mapStateToProps` doesn't return anything so calling `this.props.doSearch(...` returns `undefined`. Adding the return will give you the promise when calling `this.props.doSearch(...` and `.then` should work fine.

Comment: That worked suggestion worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You need an async function for your service, which returns a promise. Like this

```
async function doSearch(val) {

const requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    }),
    body: JSON.stringify({SearchValue})
};

const requestPath = 'http://localhost:53986/api/jobs/postsearch';    
const data = fetch(requestPath, requestOptions);
const jsonData = await data.json();

return jsonData;
}
```

Then you can call like so:

```
doSearch(val).then() // and so on...
```

This is the pattern your looking for in this case.

Comment: I got the same result.

Comment: I believe this has to do with the way you are calling your doSearch method being that the interpreter reads it as undefined.. Try simply calling it in componentDidMount just to see if things are working.

Comment: You thoughts were accurate, it seems as though it is how I am calling it. I am calling it via mapDispatchtoProps

Comment: I see that. Your dispatching looks convoluted, and def seems wrong. You'll need to check the docs and read up on proper dispatching. https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch

Comment: `return { response };` is returning an object, which would stop you from being able to call `.then` after `doSearch` in this case. If you want to keep chaining `.then`, you need to ensure the return value is a promise thru each subsequent `.then`